# Any cure for epidermolysis bullosa?

Tags: dermatology, disease, blister, epidermolysis-bullosa, cure

My young cousing has this skin disease, and that's awful. Any possible cure for this disease?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but epidermolysis bullosa doesn't have a cure, but there are ways to treat its symptoms.                                                                                                                                                      Medications can help control pain and itching and address complications such as infection in the bloodstream (sepsis). Prescription oral antibiotics may be used if you show signs of a deep or widespread infection (fever, weakness, swollen lymph glands).

An oral anti-inflammatory drug (corticosteroid) may help reduce the pain from dysphagia (difficulty swallowing).
http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/epidermolysis-bullosa/basics/treatment/con-20032497.                                                                      http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Epidermolysis-bullosa/Pages/Treatment.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is no cure as yet, but there are some treatments being used or trailed that reduce the amount of blistering.

1. In America and Japan they do bone marrow transplants for the more severe cases (but it is highly risky, and not always effective).
2. There are various trials going on with creams at the moment for various sub-types of EB, for example for EB Simplex the [Diacerein 1% ointment (CCP-020)](http://deliversebs.com/) and [Allantoin 6% for RDEB.](http://www.mdedge.com/edermatologynews/article/107789/rare-diseases/topical-allantoin-cream-speeds-wound-healing)
3. Gene-corrected skin grafts e.g. [A Dying Boy Gets a New, Gene-Corrected Skin](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2017/11/epidermolysis-bullosa-new-skin/545291/)

Also being researched but I've not seen the results for yet are

4. Research in stem cells
5. Research into culturing the patients own skin from areas where it does not blister and transplanting it back.
6. Protein replacement therapies
7. Cell-based therapies